# My video Card is not working at its best

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

I am using Ubuntu on hp pavillion g6 laptop but my video card intel HD graphics family is set always to standard and not performs best. When I minimize any application windows in my Ubuntu 12.04 the outline of the window remains on the screen and even it does not give me option to resize the doc at the left hand side. Please help me out I have installed
mesa-utils 
and updated the system

Even did the grub settings with nomodeset but do not know the grub settings Intel HD graphics Family (Sandybridge).

Comment: Usually graphics cards change when the performance requirements change.  Does it not change when it is needed?

Comment: No it does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a discrete graphics card in addition to the Intel HD Graphics? If so, you would need to install the display drivers for that card. If the card is an Nvidia and uses Optimus, you should [install Bumblebee drivers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee). If it is an AMD, you should [install radeon drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).

Comment: Sorry I am Using just Intel HD Graphics driver